# Python for iteration with previous variable

Tags: python

the function is meant to do the follow, "to get the n (non-negative integer) copies of the first 2 characters of a given string. Return the n copies of the whole string if the length is less than 2."
Can anyone tell me what does the **substr** do in line 12?
I get how it works previously on line 8 (when string is larger than 2), but it looses me on how it works on line 12, where the string is lower than 2.

```
def substring_copy(str, n):
    """
    Method 2
    """
    f_lenght = 2
    if f_lenght > len(str): # If strings length is larger than 2
        f_lenght = len(str) # Length of string will be len(str)
    substr = str[:f_lenght] # substr = str[:2] (slice 0 y 1)
    # If length is shorter than 2
    result = ""
    for i in range(n):
        result = result + substr
    return result
print ("\nMethod 2:")
print(substring_copy('abcdef', 2))
print(substring_copy('p', 3));
```

If the length of **p** is 1, then isn't it a case that **substr** isn't that important and the **for loop** will run **3** (thanks to **3*** in the last line of code)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, **substr** is important for if there are more than 2 characters in the string. When there are less than 2, **substr** could have a value of 200; the **p** string would still be just one **p** and that would concatenate n times (3 times in this example).

Answer (score 0):

So as you inferred `substr` is just the *substr*ing of length 2 (or less) from the original, which can be the input itself if it's already 2 or less.

It's your "duplication target", basically.

Though I do want to point out that the entire thing is a rather bad style, it is over-complicated and doesn't make good use of python:

- `str` is the python string type (which also acts as a conversion function), it's a builtin, shadowing builtin is a bad idea and str is a common builtin, naming a variable `str` is terrible style, sometimes it's justifiable, but not here
- python slicing is "bounded" to what it's slicing, so e.g. `"ab"[:5]` will return `"ab"`, unlike regular indexing it does not care that the input is too short, this means the entire mess with `f_lenght` is unnecessary, you can just

  ```
  substr = s[:2]
  ```
- Python strings have an override for multiplication, `str * n` repeats the string n times, this also works with lists (though that is more risky because of mutability and reference semantics)

So the entire function could just be:

```
def substring_copy(s, n):
    return s[:2] * n
```

The prompt is also not great because of the ambiguity of the word "character", but I guess we can let that slide

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I'm new to coding and it didn't think much of that solution they gave me...
I initially started out with:
`code`
def get_first_two(self):
    slice01 = self[0:2]
    return (slice01)*2
`code`

Comment: Yeah your code is not ideal (naming is not great, `0` is unnecessary, and the parens in the final expression aren't eiter), but I would say it is a better effort than what's in the question. What's in the question looks like it has been ported from an other language with rather different and more rigid APIs. Probably Java, given the naming.